# Through the ocean or in the ocean

Tags: prepositions

In an essay should say I swim *in the ocean* or *through the ocean*. For sailing what should we say?

Comment: You swim in the ocean, you sail in the ocean. Sail through is mainly used metaphorically https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sail%20through

Comment: ...circumnavigating Africa from the Mediterranean , it was necessary to sail through the ocean close to the Canaries . https://books.google.it/books?id=uCZmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sail+through+the+ocean%22&dq=%22sail+through+the+ocean%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU1eWbq5bwAhVP26QKHYsFAz0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAw

Comment: @user66974 Usually you sail _on_ the ocean rather than _in_ it.

Comment: ... but 'We were sailing in the Mediterranean' (the container metaphor; seas seen as enclosed readily (even preferentially) accept 'in'. The Caspian, Baltic ... even the Caribbean. // 'We sailed the Seven Seas' uses a straight DO rather than a PP (sometimes also seen as a DO), but it's in a literary register.

Comment: .... But for some instruments like submarines or diver we can use “through the ocean” , or not ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

P.S.  Soit,
Swim is an irregular verb in English.
Swim, swam, swum

Swim is an irregular verb; swam is the past tense of swim, while swum is the past participle. Swum is used after have, as in "I have swum in that pool before." ... Another might say that they, too, have swum in it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It doesn't mention sailing or address the question of "in" versus "on" at all. I'm not sure why you are talking about "swum", that's not what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Swimming implies emersion (IN) the water. We swim in the water to a destination.
When we travel by ship/boat/etc. we generally sail (ON) the water. Sailing implies riding on the surface of the water in a vessel of some kind.
First Case/eg: "I swam from one side of the lake to the other."
Second Case/eg: "I took a ship to London from N.Y. We made the voyage in 7 days, effortlessly sailing, in beautiful weather on the Atlantic Ocean".

Language is a living thing and is best learned by **listening, reading and speaking** the language.
Good luck, Soit

Comment: Hello, Mark. Please look at the Help Center and a few questions/answers to get a feel of the site and its 'mission statement'. This question is too basic for ELU, which is aimed at proficient speakers; there are many other sites aimed at helping with basic questions. This question as it stands should be closed rather than answered. Answers containing more rigorous analysis of preposition choice need supporting references.

Comment: Edwin Thank you for your insights. I will re-direct my efforts and visit the **Help Center**
seeking clarity and focus. I will also read the 'mission statement'. Then, I can tailor any words of advice as appropriate.
Mark

Comment: @Mark You may have created two accounts. If you can still log into one of them, please see our [help on how to merge them](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).